# configure: error: –with-ssl=openssl was given，but ssl is not available

Tags: linux

I'm trying to configure wget1.13.4.

```
configure: error: –with-ssl=openssl was given, but ssl is not available.
```

I have installed libssl-dev but it didn't work.
Does anyone konw how to fix it?

Comment: The file `https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Debugging.html` might contatin more details about the problem. Please [edit] your question and show the relevant part of this file.

Comment: config.log file that was created by configure script contains the answer. It looks that the test program for openssl tries to link with libz library. If it's missing it would say that there is no openssl. Install libz-dev and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with OpenSSL 2.1.3 and Curl 8.3.0:

The libcurl configuration script searches for a subdirectory with the name "/lib" in the OpenSSL installation, but the setup may use the name "/lib64". After moving "/lib64" to /lib", the error message should disappear.